# Keeping iAds in landscape SpriteKit / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, orientation, iad

In my game, all scenes are in landscape. I implemented iAd banners to be in landscape mode on the bottom of the screen. However, when I click on it and it loads, it changes its orientation to portrait. When I exit the ad, the game returns to normal. Is it possible to keep ads in landscape mode when loaded? Below is the code I used for creating iAds.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  /*  var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd) */

    UIiAd.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)
    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView":UIiAd]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.alpha = 1 // Fade in the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func showBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = false
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(10) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - BV, 2048, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func hideBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = true
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.UIiAd.hidden = true
    self.UIiAd.alpha = 0

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideBannerAd", name: "hideadsID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showBannerAd", name: "showadsID", object: nil)

    let scene = MainMenu(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1356))
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    println("Clicked")
    return true
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

}
```

I call this method in GameScene

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207546/iad-banner-displays-with-portrait-orientation-even-though-window-is-landscape You need to use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`

Comment: What I am looking for is how to keep the iAd in landscape when it is clicked. It turns to portrait while it goes fullscreen, and although it turns back to normal after it closes, it does not look good when it loads. @Kendel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue mainly applies only to the test ads delivered by iAd during development. Most live banner ads that will appear in your application, once your application is live on the App Store, will support both landscape and portrait layouts when a user taps on the ad.

There is no way to force an ad to re-layout for landscape when it was built to display in portrait only, and vice versa.

Comment: So Apple's test iAds only support portrait? @DanielStorm

Comment: In relation to once you tap on the ad, yes.